# Instantiating widgets in a loop to different frames python/tkinter

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, tkinter, widget

I am creating a simple GUI production calculator in python. I am using Tkinter and have a main frame with 10 tabs in it. I have created all the entries and functions do do the calculations we need and it all works. My problem is that i want these entries and labels on each tab line10 - line19. I could manually recreate the code for each tab  but that does not seem very pythonic. What I am hoping for is to be able to put this code in a loop that will rename the variable names for each line and place the objects into the different tab frames by changing the argument in the grid methods. I hope I am being clear enough I am very new and hoping to get a good grasp of this language. I am hoping to be able to just reiterate this code with a different number at the end of all the variable names, would concatenation work?

here is my code.

```
from Tkinter import *
from ttk import *
import time


class supervisorcalc:
    def __init__(self, master):


        self.notebook = Notebook(master)

        self.line10 = Frame(self.notebook);
        self.notebook.add(self.line10, text="Line 10")

        self.line11 = Frame(self.notebook);
        self.notebook.add(self.line11, text="Line 11")

        self.line12 = Frame(self.notebook);
        self.notebook.add(self.line12, text="Line 12")

        self.line13 = Frame(self.notebook);
        self.notebook.add(self.line13, text="Line 13")

        self.line14 = Frame(self.notebook);
        self.notebook.add(self.line14, text="Line 14")

        self.line15 = Frame(self.notebook);
        self.notebook.add(self.line15, text="Line 15")

        self.line16 = Frame(self.notebook);
        self.notebook.add(self.line16, text="Line 16")

        self.line17 = Frame(self.notebook);
        self.notebook.add(self.line17, text="Line 17")

        self.line18 = Frame(self.notebook);
        self.notebook.add(self.line18, text="Line 18")

        self.line19 = Frame(self.notebook);
        self.notebook.add(self.line19, text="Line 19")





        self.notebook.grid(row=0,column=0)

        ###functions###

        def cyclecnt(*args):
            cyclecount = int(self.cyccnt.get())
            molds = int(self.vj.get())
            cyccount = cyclecount * molds
            self.cyc.set(cyccount)            
            return


        def currentproduction(*args):
            item = int(self.item.get())
            case = int(self.case.get())
            currprod = item * case
            self.production.set(currprod)
            return

        def lostunits(*args):
            cycle = int(self.cyc.get())
            prod = int(self.production.get())
            self.loss.set(cycle - prod)
            return

        def efficiency(*args):
            lost = float(self.loss.get())
            prod = float(self.production.get())
            self.efficiency.set((lost/prod)*100)
            return

        def getSec(x):
            l = x.split(':')
            return int(l[0]) * 3600 + int(l[1]) * 60 + int(l[2])

        def future_time_seconds(*args):
            hrs = self.hour.get()
            mins = self.minute.get()
            return (int(hrs) * 3600) + (int(mins) * 60)

        def time_difference_seconds(*args):
            fseconds = future_time_seconds()
            s = time.strftime('%I:%M:%S')
            cursecs = getSec(s)
            return fseconds - cursecs

        def proj(*args):
            ctime = float(self.cycletime.get())
            prod = int(self.production.get())
            loss = int(self.loss.get())
            case = float(self.case.get())
            molds = int(self.vj.get())
            item = int(self.item.get())
            seconds = time_difference_seconds()
            pcycle = ((molds / ctime) * seconds)
            projeff = float(self.peff.get()) / float(100)
            pproduction = pcycle - (pcycle * projeff)
            self.projectedprod.set(prod + pproduction)                     
            projloss = loss + pcycle * projeff
            self.ploss.set(projloss)

            fcase = case + (pproduction / float(item))
            self.fcase.set(fcase)


        ###line 19



        self.ctlabelj = Label(self.line19, text = "Cycle Time:")
        self.ctlabelj.grid(row=2, column=0)
        self.cycletime = StringVar()
        self.cycletime.trace('w', proj)
        self.cycletimeentj = Entry(self.line19, textvariable=self.cycletime)
        self.cycletimeentj.grid(row=2,column=1)

        moldoptionsj = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4]
        self.vj = IntVar()
        self.vj.set(moldoptionsj[0])
        self.headslabelj = Label(self.line19, text = "# of Molds:")
        self.headslabelj.grid(row=3, column=0)
        self.headcomboj = OptionMenu(self.line19, self.vj, *moldoptionsj)
        self.headcomboj.grid(row=3,column=1)
        self.vj.trace("w", cyclecnt)

        self.cclabelj = Label(self.line19, text = "Cycle Count:")
        self.cclabelj.grid(row=4, column=0)
        self.cyccnt = StringVar()
        self.cyclecountentj = Entry(self.line19, textvariable=self.cyccnt)
        self.cyclecountentj.grid(row=4,column=1)
        self.cyccnt.trace("w", cyclecnt)


        self.ipcj = Label(self.line19, text = "Items/Case:")
        self.ipcj.grid(row=5, column=0)
        self.item = StringVar()
        self.ipcentj = Entry(self.line19, textvariable=self.item)
        self.ipcentj.grid(row=5,column=1)
        self.item.trace("w", currentproduction)

        self.currj = Label(self.line19, text = "Current Case #:")
        self.currj.grid(row=6, column=0)
        self.case = StringVar()
        self.currentj = Entry(self.line19, textvariable=self.case)
        self.currentj.grid(row=6,column=1)
        self.case.trace("w", currentproduction)


        self.ctimej = Label(self.line19, text = "Current Time:")
        self.ctimej.grid(row=7, column=0, sticky='W')
        self.clockj = Label(self.line19)
        self.clockj.grid(row=7,column=1, sticky='w')

        ####futureztime###
        self.futureframe = Frame(self.line19)
        self.futureframe.grid(row=8, column=1)
        self.futurej = Label(self.line19, text = "Future Projections time:")
        self.futurej.grid(row=8, column=0, sticky='w')
        self.hour = StringVar()
        self.hour.trace('w', time_difference_seconds)
        self.hour.trace('w', proj)
        self.futureenthourj = Entry(self.futureframe, width=2, textvariable=self.hour)
        self.futureenthourj.grid(row=0, column=0) 
        self.futurecolonj = Label(self.futureframe, text = ":")
        self.futurecolonj.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.minute = StringVar()
        self.minute.trace('w', time_difference_seconds)
        self.minute.trace('w', proj)
        self.futureentminj = Entry(self.futureframe, width=2, textvariable=self.minute)
        self.futureentminj.grid(row=0, column=2)
        ####

        self.cycleslabel = Label(self.line19, text = 'Cycle Total:')
        self.cycleslabel.grid(row=2, column=2)
        self.cyc = StringVar()
        self.cyc.set("00000")
        self.cyc.trace('w', lostunits)
        self.cycles = Label(self.line19, foreground = 'green', background = 'black', text = "00000", textvariable = self.cyc)
        self.cycles.grid(row=2, column=3)

        self.currprodkeylabel = Label(self.line19, text = 'Current Production:')
        self.currprodkeylabel.grid(row=3, column=2)
        self.production = StringVar()
        self.production.set('00000')
        self.production.trace('w', lostunits)
        self.production.trace('w', efficiency)
        self.currentprod = Label(self.line19, foreground = 'green', background = 'black', textvariable=self.production)
        self.currentprod.grid(row=3, column=3)

        self.prodprojkeylabel = Label(self.line19, text = 'Projected Production:')
        self.prodprojkeylabel.grid(row=4, column=2)
        self.projectedprod = StringVar()
        self.projectedprod.set('00000')
        self.prodproj = Label(self.line19, foreground = 'green', background = 'black', textvariable=self.projectedprod )
        self.prodproj.grid(row=4, column=3)

        self.losskeylabel = Label(self.line19, text = 'Lost units:')
        self.losskeylabel.grid(row=5, column=2)
        self.loss = StringVar()
        self.loss.set("0000")
        self.loss.trace('w', efficiency)
        self.lossprod = Label(self.line19, foreground = 'green', background = 'black', textvariable=self.loss)
        self.lossprod.grid(row=5, column=3)

        self.plosskeylabel = Label(self.line19, text = 'Projected Lost units:')
        self.plosskeylabel.grid(row=6, column=2)
        self.ploss = StringVar()
        self.ploss.set("0000")
        self.plossprod = Label(self.line19, foreground = 'green', background = 'black', textvariable=self.ploss)
        self.plossprod.grid(row=6, column=3)

        self.currefficiencykeylabel = Label(self.line19, text = 'Current efficiency %:')
        self.currefficiencykeylabel.grid(row=7, column=2)
        self.efficiency = StringVar()
        self.efficiency.set("00.00")
        self.currentefficiency = Label(self.line19, foreground = 'green', background = 'black', textvariable=self.efficiency)
        self.currentefficiency.grid(row=7, column=3)

        self.futurecaselabel = Label(self.line19, text = 'Future case # projection:')
        self.futurecaselabel.grid(row=8, column=2)
        self.fcase = StringVar()
        self.fcase.set("000.0")
        self.futurecase = Label(self.line19, foreground = 'green', background = 'black', textvariable=self.fcase)
        self.futurecase.grid(row=8, column=3)

        self.projefficiencylabel = Label(self.line19, text = "Efficiency Projection:")
        self.projefficiencylabel.grid(row=9, column=2)
        self.peff = StringVar()
        self.peff.set(0.00)
        self.peff.trace('w', proj)
        self.projefficiency = Entry(self.line19, textvariable=self.peff)
        self.projefficiency.grid(row=9,column=3)






        def tick():
            s = time.strftime('%I:%M:%S')
            if s != self.clockj:

                self.clockj.configure(text=s)
            self.notebook.after(200, tick)

        tick()





root = Tk()
root.wm_title("Hillside Plastics Production Calculator")
calc = supervisorcalc(root)

mainloop()
```

Comment: Have you tried using a loop, as noted in the tags?

Comment: You can save yourself several lines of code by _not_ using `StringVar`s for your labels. In fact, you really never need to use `StringVar`s for labels or entry widgets unless you're taking advantage of the special `StringVar` features such as tracing, or tying the display of two or more widgets together.

Answer (score 0):

The pythonic solution is to make each notebook tab an instance of a custom class. It would look something like this:

```
class NotebookTab(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.create_widgets()

        def create_widgets(self):
            self.ctlabelj = Label(self, text = "Cycle Time:")
            self.ctlabelj.grid(row=2, column=0)
            self.cycletime = StringVar()
            self.cycletime.trace('w', proj)
            self.cycletimeentj = Entry(self, textvariable=self.cycletime)
            self.cycletimeentj.grid(row=2,column=1)

            moldoptionsj = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4]
            self.vj = IntVar()
            ...

for linenumber in range(10, 20):
    tab = NotebookTab(notebook, text="Line %d" % linenumber)
    notebook.add(self)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's easy using a loop: look at (I think there's only one problem)…

```
from Tkinter import *
from ttk import *
import time

class supervisorcalc:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.notebook = Notebook(master)
        self.lines = {}

        for i in range(10, 20):
            self.lines[i] = Frame(self.notebook)
            self.notebook.add(self.lines[i], text="Line" +  str(i))

        self.notebook.grid(row=0,column=0)

        ###functions###

        def cyclecnt(*args):
            cyclecount = int(self.cyccnt.get())
            molds = int(self.vj.get())
            cyccount = cyclecount * molds
            self.cyc.set(cyccount)            
            return

        def currentproduction(*args):
            item = int(self.item.get())
            case = int(self.case.get())
            currprod = item * case
            self.production.set(currprod)
            return

        def lostunits(*args):
            cycle = int(self.cyc.get())
            prod = int(self.production.get())
            self.loss.set(cycle - prod)
            return

        def efficiency(*args):
            lost = float(self.loss.get())
            prod = float(self.production.get())
            self.efficiency.set((lost/prod)*100)
            return

        def getSec(x):
            l = x.split(':')
            return int(l[0]) * 3600 + int(l[1]) * 60 + int(l[2])

        def future_time_seconds(*args):
            hrs = self.hour.get()
            mins = self.minute.get()
            return (int(hrs) * 3600) + (int(mins) * 60)

        def time_difference_seconds(*args):
            fseconds = future_time_seconds()
            s = time.strftime('%I:%M:%S')
            cursecs = getSec(s)
            return fseconds - cursecs

        def proj(*args):
            ctime = float(self.cycletime.get())
            prod = int(self.production.get())
            loss = int(self.loss.get())
            case = float(self.case.get())
            molds = int(self.vj.get())
            item = int(self.item.get())
            seconds = time_difference_seconds()
            pcycle = ((molds / ctime) * seconds)
            projeff = float(self.peff.get()) / float(100)
            pproduction = pcycle - (pcycle * projeff)
            self.projectedprod.set(prod + pproduction)                     
            projloss = loss + pcycle * projeff
            self.ploss.set(projloss)

            fcase = case + (pproduction / float(item))
            self.fcase.set(fcase)

        ###line 19
            # Look after the function   

        def widg_on_panes(self, num):
            self.ctlabelj = Label(self.lines[num], text = "Cycle Time:")
            self.ctlabelj.grid(row=2, column=0)
            self.cycletime = StringVar()
            self.cycletime.trace('w', proj)
            self.cycletimeentj = Entry(self.lines[num], textvariable=self.cycletime)
            self.cycletimeentj.grid(row=2,column=1)

            moldoptionsj = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4]
            self.vj = IntVar()
            self.vj.set(moldoptionsj[0])
            self.headslabelj = Label(self.lines[num], text = "# of Molds:")
            self.headslabelj.grid(row=3, column=0)
            self.headcomboj = OptionMenu(self.lines[num], self.vj, *moldoptionsj)
            self.headcomboj.grid(row=3,column=1)
            self.vj.trace("w", cyclecnt)

            self.cclabelj = Label(self.lines[num], text = "Cycle Count:")
            self.cclabelj.grid(row=4, column=0)
            self.cyccnt = StringVar()
            self.cyclecountentj = Entry(self.lines[num], textvariable=self.cyccnt)
            self.cyclecountentj.grid(row=4,column=1)
            self.cyccnt.trace("w", cyclecnt)

            self.ipcj = Label(self.lines[num], text = "Items/Case:")
            self.ipcj.grid(row=5, column=0)
            self.item = StringVar()
            self.ipcentj = Entry(self.lines[num], textvariable=self.item)
            self.ipcentj.grid(row=5,column=1)
            self.item.trace("w", currentproduction)

            self.currj = Label(self.lines[num], text = "Current Case #:")
            self.currj.grid(row=6, column=0)
            self.case = StringVar()
            self.currentj = Entry(self.lines[num], textvariable=self.case)
            self.currentj.grid(row=6,column=1)
            self.case.trace("w", currentproduction)

            self.ctimej = Label(self.lines[num], text = "Current Time:")
            self.ctimej.grid(row=7, column=0, sticky='W')
            self.clockj = Label(self.lines[num])
            self.clockj.grid(row=7,column=1, sticky='w')

            ####futureztime###
            self.futureframe = Frame(self.lines[num])
            self.futureframe.grid(row=8, column=1)
            self.futurej = Label(self.lines[num], text = "Future Projections time:")
            self.futurej.grid(row=8, column=0, sticky='w')
            self.hour = StringVar()
            self.hour.trace('w', time_difference_seconds)
            self.hour.trace('w', proj)
            self.futureenthourj = Entry(self.futureframe, width=2, textvariable=self.hour)
            self.futureenthourj.grid(row=0, column=0) 
            self.futurecolonj = Label(self.futureframe, text = ":")
            self.futurecolonj.grid(row=0, column=1)
            self.minute = StringVar()
            self.minute.trace('w', time_difference_seconds)
            self.minute.trace('w', proj)
            self.futureentminj = Entry(self.futureframe, width=2, textvariable=self.minute)
            self.futureentminj.grid(row=0, column=2)
            ####

            self.cycleslabel = Label(self.lines[num], text = 'Cycle Total:')
            self.cycleslabel.grid(row=2, column=2)
            self.cyc = StringVar()
            self.cyc.set("00000")
            self.cyc.trace('w', lostunits)
            self.cycles = Label(self.lines[num], foreground = 'green', background = 'black', text = "00000", textvariable = self.cyc)
            self.cycles.grid(row=2, column=3)

            self.currprodkeylabel = Label(self.lines[num], text = 'Current Production:')
            self.currprodkeylabel.grid(row=3, column=2)
            self.production = StringVar()
            self.production.set('00000')
            self.production.trace('w', lostunits)
            self.production.trace('w', efficiency)
            self.currentprod = Label(self.lines[num], foreground = 'green', background = 'black', textvariable=self.production)
            self.currentprod.grid(row=3, column=3)

            self.prodprojkeylabel = Label(self.lines[num], text = 'Projected Production:')
            self.prodprojkeylabel.grid(row=4, column=2)
            self.projectedprod = StringVar()
            self.projectedprod.set('00000')
            self.prodproj = Label(self.lines[num], foreground = 'green', background = 'black', textvariable=self.projectedprod )
            self.prodproj.grid(row=4, column=3)

            self.losskeylabel = Label(self.lines[num], text = 'Lost units:')
            self.losskeylabel.grid(row=5, column=2)
            self.loss = StringVar()
            self.loss.set("0000")
            self.loss.trace('w', efficiency)
            self.lossprod = Label(self.lines[num], foreground = 'green', background = 'black', textvariable=self.loss)
            self.lossprod.grid(row=5, column=3)

            self.plosskeylabel = Label(self.lines[num], text = 'Projected Lost units:')
            self.plosskeylabel.grid(row=6, column=2)
            self.ploss = StringVar()
            self.ploss.set("0000")
            self.plossprod = Label(self.lines[num], foreground = 'green', background = 'black', textvariable=self.ploss)
            self.plossprod.grid(row=6, column=3)

            self.currefficiencykeylabel = Label(self.lines[num], text = 'Current efficiency %:')
            self.currefficiencykeylabel.grid(row=7, column=2)
            self.efficiency = StringVar()
            self.efficiency.set("00.00")
            self.currentefficiency = Label(self.lines[num], foreground = 'green', background = 'black', textvariable=self.efficiency)
            self.currentefficiency.grid(row=7, column=3)

            self.futurecaselabel = Label(self.lines[num], text = 'Future case # projection:')
            self.futurecaselabel.grid(row=8, column=2)
            self.fcase = StringVar()
            self.fcase.set("000.0")
            self.futurecase = Label(self.lines[num], foreground = 'green', background = 'black', textvariable=self.fcase)
            self.futurecase.grid(row=8, column=3)

            self.projefficiencylabel = Label(self.lines[num], text = "Efficiency Projection:")
            self.projefficiencylabel.grid(row=9, column=2)
            self.peff = StringVar()
            self.peff.set(0.00)
            self.peff.trace('w', proj)
            self.projefficiency = Entry(self.lines[num], textvariable=self.peff)
            self.projefficiency.grid(row=9,column=3)

        for num in self.lines.keys():
            widg_on_panes(self, num)  

        def tick():
            s = time.strftime('%I:%M:%S')
            if s != self.clockj:

                self.clockj.configure(text=s)
            self.notebook.after(200, tick)

        tick()

root = Tk()
root.wm_title("Hillside Plastics Production Calculator")
calc = supervisorcalc(root)

mainloop()
```

Comment: Ok My question now is why does each tab's entry widgets retain their input values when you switch tabs even though they have the same variable name? But yet none of the functions for calculating the math work on them?   Do i need to make a dictionary for each widget and make a loop for each function? would that even work?

Comment: @HermesTrismegistus: well, i think so. You have to make variables for all of your panels. And making dictionary might be a solution! How can you have 9 `entry` without having 9 vars to see them? All your `StringVar` might be in dictionary and all things that can differ  between panels must be panel dependent (ie: have it's own vars)! No? Some people prefer not using `StringVar` for entry but`get` and `set`, but here same thing: you have to make a dictionary to access all those entry! Yes